# Help renaming svn repository

Tags: svn, rename

Here is the deal:

1. I created an SVN repository, say, foo. It is at `http://www.example.com/foo`.
2. Then I did an svn checkout.
3. I made some updates and changes to my local copy of the code over the week. I haven't committed yet.
4. I realized that I wanted to rename the repository. So I did this:

svn copy `http://example.com/foo` `http://example.com/bar`

svn delete `http://example.com/foo`

4. I finish my changes (and local svn still thinks I'm working under "foo".) `svn commit` fails because the repo has been renamed.
5. I try to use `svn switch --relocate` but it yells at me because svn is awful.
6. I try using the script [here](http://www.mi-ange.net/blog/msg.php?id=63&lng=en) to replace "foo" with "bar" in my billion .svn/ folders.
7. This replace is taking a long time. I wonder if something hung? Or maybe sshfs failed? I kill it. Ctrl-C.
8. I look and see that half my files have "foo" and the others have "bar" in the URLs in the sundry .svn/ folders.

All I want to do is commit my files with the new name. I could re-checkout the branch, but then I have no way to remember which files I changed, which is why I was using version control in the first place, and svn is so godawful at moving and renaming things.

What do I need to do to:

1. Have a "clean" copy of my "bar" svn branch? and, most importantly:
2. Commit the changes I made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--relocate is only used for base URL changes.

Try svn cleanup then svn switch --force

Comment: I did an "svn cleanup" (which took a while but didn't really do anything - different "entries" files still had different URLs) and then did an "svn switch" - without the --force. This did the trick. I thought "switch" would clobber my local changes but then I looked at the manual a bit closer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you do need to checkout a fresh version and then make all your changes again it should be a fairly simply process of just pushing them over to the new checkout - you don't need to remember them, use a tool like Beyond Compare to quickly show you the diffs and copy them over.

Even when source control is working perfectly I spend a fair bit of time reviewing diffs (ie: before commit etc).

Comment: hm, that makes me think: could I just do a `diff` on the two directories, ignoring ".svn" folders, and then `patch`? Do you know how that might work?

Comment: Could do - I'm not that familiar with the patch command in SVN (don't do much directly on its command line sorry).  But its the same principle I believe as using a compare tool and applying changes directly to the files line by line.